# 60s/70s story, dying man repairs alien machine, survives because machine pipes 'life force' not electricity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

A short story, found in a magazine or anthology sometime definitely before mid 1980s, but I think I read it in the 1970s.

The protagonist is dying but manages to repair a machine before he does so, in order that the girl he's met can live. He collapses but wakes to find himself alive — the girl explains that the wiring in the machine carried not electricity but rather some sort of life force and the leakage had brought him back to life.

They were on a distant planet and possibly (I'm not sure if it was the same story) they had been transplanted into crocodilian bodies.

(removed my comment about "The Ferryman on the River Styx" which wasn't the story)

Posted about this on AbeBooks BookSleuth in 2007.

Comment: Yes, The Ferryman... was a red herring.